# Biblatex not printing the bibliography in pdf

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to create a bibliography with .bib file but it don't print in pdf.

My bib file has this structure:

```
 @book{latexcompanion,
    author        = {Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin},
    title         = {The \LaTeX\ Companion},
    year          = {1993},
    publisher     = {Addison-Wesley},
    location      = {Reading, Massachusetts}
}
```

and my file has this aspect:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}        
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{report.bib}

    \begin{document}
        \chapter{Bibliografia}
        ola \cite{latexcompanion}
        \printbibliography

        \chapter{Anexos}

    \end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Cumps.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Did you run `pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex`?

Comment: Completing your code and taking out the gratuitous `}` results in code that compiles just fine for me. Like @cfr asked, are you running the correct compilation sequence? See [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number)

Comment: thanks for your answers.. I have a lot of code, and I'm hiding some parts to be more legible.
I've edited the post.. It still don't work.

Comment: @cfr I get 3 error when I run bibtex..

Comment: Problem solved. I get an error when I'm compiling, but if I compile twice the problem is solved. Thank you all

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP has reported that the problem has been solved by following the correct sequence of compilation. Furthermore, the issue was trivial, discussed extensively before, and hence does not merit further consideration.

Comment: @Masroor Should I delete it?

Comment: @arturataide Yes, you may wish to delete the question. Moreover, there are three close votes already, so it will get closed eventually.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just a suggestion. Using the same .bib file, it will be a lot easier if you will try this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Bibliografia}
ola \cite{latexcompanion}.

\chapter{Anexos}

\bibliography{report}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution in my project, but it fails to compile..

Comment: Try to compile it at least twice.

Comment: hank you very much.. If i compile twice it runs ok :) Thank you

Comment: Why exactly is this a 'lot easier' than using `biber`? @arturataide I don't think this is good advice. `biblatex` and `biber` is a much more powerful combination. Unless you have to, those were good choices. The only thing you did wrong was to run `bibtex` rather than `biber`. That is, you needed `pdflatex` **`biber`** `pdflatex`. `biber` is a modern replacement for `bibtex` which definitely makes life easier.